# iOS 1Password like navigation

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiview, uisplitview

I'm trying to figure out how to implement a navigation bar like in the 1Password iPad app

https://www.dropbox.com/s/t0gfdwvmji48wor/1password_navi.png

I implemented a UISplitView but I'm not sure how to bring in my custom navigation bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the link below. It's essentially a `UITableView` underneath, so you can add as many tabs as you like.

https://github.com/futuresimple/FSVerticalTabBarController

Comment: To use it in conjunction with a UISplitView I would suggest MGSplitViewController https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController